# Where is the documentation to accomplish an orderly shutdown of IBM Cloud Private?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

IBM Cloud Private-CE (Community Edition) 2.1.0.2 is up and running on my repurposed 32-gigabyte laptop.
VMware ESXi 6.5 (vSphere Hypervisor) is the bare metal hypervisor.  The environment is up and running.
http://icpmster:8443/console 
is serving beautifully constructed pages.

The Knowledge Center guided me this far on my IBM Cloud Private journey.  It is silent on how to accomplish an orderly shutdown of an ICP cluster (1).

Google Search results provide no guidance.

My motivation is a home base to return to from my ICP application deployment adventures.
That is,

- stop the environment.
- take ESXi virtual machine snapshots to provide  a baseline state of the cluster
- restart the virtual machines
- install software packages and deploy applications
- return to the baseline after completing business valued use cases

Where is the documentation to accomplish an orderly shutdown of IBM Cloud Private?

Thank you for your assistance, 
regards, Chris

**Footnotes**
(1)  What I have read again, and again, and again …

```
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Release Notes” > “Known issues and limitations” > “Docker 17.12-ce is not supported”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Release Notes” > “Known issues and limitations” > “IPv6 is not supported”
  * “IPv6 is not supported”
  * “Docker 17.12-ce is not supported”, “Docker version 17.09-ce is the latest stable version of Docker CE that is supported by IBM Cloud Private.”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Overview” > “IBM Cloud Private overview”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Overview” > “IBM Cloud Private bundles”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Overview” > “Architecture”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Overview” > “Components”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Installing” > “System Requirements” > “Hardware requirements and recommendations”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Installing” > “System Requirements” > “Supported operating systems and platforms”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Installing” > “System Requirements” > “Supported Docker versions”
IBM Cloud Private is not supported on Docker 17.12-ce, see 
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Release notes” > “Docker 17.12-ce is not supported”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Installing” > “Configuring options during installation” > “Setting up Docker for IBM Cloud Private”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Installing” > “Configuring options during installation” > “Setting up Docker for IBM Cloud Private” > “Installing from the Docker website”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Installing” > “Configuring options during installation” > “Setting up Docker for IBM Cloud Private” > “Configuring your Docker engine”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Installing” > “Configuring options during installation” > “Sharing SSH keys among cluster nodes”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Installing” > “Configuring options during installation” > “Setting the node roles in the hosts file”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Installing” > “Configuring options during installation” > “Customizing your installation”
  * Vulnerability Advisor is not available for IBM Cloud Private-CE (Community Edition)
  * Multiple Clusters (Federation) Technical Preview not available for IBM Cloud Private-CE (Community Edition)
  * High Availability is supported for IBM Cloud Private Cloud Native and Enterprise editions only.
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Installing” > “Configuring options during installation” > “Configuring the monitoring service”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Installing” > “Configuring options during installation” > “Customizing the cluster with the config.yaml file”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Installing” > “Prepare your cluster for installation”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Installing” > “Prepare your cluster for installation” > “Configuring your cluster”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Installing” > “Installing IBM Cloud Private” > “IBM Cloud Private CE”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Troubleshooting and support” > “Installation” > “Installation hangs or fails”
“IBM Cloud Private v2.1.0.2” > “Uninstalling” > “Uninstall IBM Cloud Private-CE”
```

Answer (score 0):

to shutdown ICP you have to stop docker on each node.

```
systemctl stop docker
```

I would say you should stop the master nodes the first ones to avoid, in case you have several workers, that it moves loads from a worker being stopped to a running one.

Answer (score 0):

oficial restart documentation https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0/manage_cluster/restart_cluster.html